# Deployment Package doesn't contain all latest files

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2013, teamcity

I'm trying to deploy a solution, but every time I try to deploy (either using one click deployment in visual studio or teamcity). My deployment doesn't seem to have all the files that should be there.

I've set up the publish profile using Webdeploy in visual studio. What I have noticed is that the deployment package (which ends up in an Obj folder within the project directory) doesn't seem to include the files as I would expect them to. E.G, there was a file in my App_Config folder which I renamed, the package doesn't have either the file (in the old/new format)...

I've tried deleting everything on the target machine, so I am sure that the deployment is working, it just doesn't seem to be packaging correctly before deployment

Any ideas?

Thanks
Nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying to work out why some files haven't been deploying, it seems that you can define the build action on a per file basis, for some reason this one file I needed didn't have the the same build action as other similar files.

If you have similar problems, hopefully you'll find this answer and won't spend days trying to resolve it like I did with trial and error. All you need to do is;

1. Right click on the file in solution explorer,
2. Click properties
3. Set the appropriate 'Build Action' (for me it seems the appropriate Build Action was Content.)
4. Make sure that the 'Copy To Output Directory' has the appropriate configuration for your needs. For my purposes I set this to 'Copy Always'